# Selenium - Get List of XPaths of First Level elements under body

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to take the screenshot of each element directly under the `body` tag of a webpage

I have written the sample script -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

fox = webdriver.Firefox()
fox.get('http://google.com/')

# get list of elements
elements = fox.find_elements_by_xpath("//html/body")
```

After this, how do I find the XPath of each element and take a screenshot?

I have the script to take screenshot given the XPath of a single element

```
element = fox.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"hplogo\"]")
location = element.location
size = element.size
png = fox.get_screenshot_as_png() # saves screenshot of entire page
fox.quit()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = (location['x'] + size['width'])
bottom = (location['y'] + size['height'])

im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png') # saves new cropped image
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit confusing that you say you want to grab screenshots of elements

> "directly under the `body` tag "

but in the second code sniplet you want to grab the logo (`'//*[@id=\"hplogo\"]'`) which is *not a direct child of the `body`*. So my solution is based on an assumption that you would like to save "some elements" as image but not necessarily only the direct child nodes of the `body`.

Let's say you want to grab *all* the elements and deal with filtering later. Just grab all but the (not so screenshot-worthy) `script` elements under the `body`:

```py
elements = fox.find_elements_by_xpath('//html/body//*[not(self::script)]')
```

Then you can just save them without PIL, luckily selenium has the ability to save a screenshot about a given element:

```py
# leading zeroes for filenames
padding = len(str(len(elements)))

for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    # you probably don't want a 0 byte screenshot or a try/except block
    if not(element.rect['height'] and element.rect['width']):
        continue
    # don't forget to specify your target dir
    with open(os.path.join(target_dir, f'{str(i).zfill(padding)}.png'), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(element.screenshot_as_png)
```

You could improve this by saving only non-dupes, also having the right element list may save a lot of time.